# ssis handling of oracle and teradata passwords

Tags: oracle, authentication, ssis, teradata

This has gotten so bad I have to ask if there is a newer feature in ssis (like maybe vs 2017) that handles oracle and teradata passwords.   We work in a secure organization.  They don't want us leaving passwords in the packages for security reasons (I understand that ssis encrypts passwords it knows are passwords in the .dtsx file) so we have to clear them when development is done.  We also use what might be called a password vault for oracle and teradata passwords for our run time jobs which makes the transition from client development to batch job difficult.    Can anyone tell me why it would ever be useful for ssis to attempt a login to Oracle or Teradata when ssis knows the password it has is null or blanks?  A more paranoid part of me might think that Microsoft, with Windows Auth, is trying to drive their users off of Oracle or Teradata.  So is there some ssis job level parameter I can set that instructs ssis not to attempt an oracle or teradata access for metadata unless it has a password?   Some of our jobs access oracle or teradata in 5 or 10 different places, running in there to set Work Offline or Delay Validation for each one of those accesses is difficult.  And I don't want to be told to set Oracle and Teradata to use Windows Auth (if that's even possible).   I don't control that and I need something that I, as an etl developer, control.   I can't believe SSIS competes with products like Datastage with the situation concerning Oracle and Teradata passwords being so bad.

Comment: Can you add some punctuation to your question? Do you use SSIS environments? This is how you're mean to manage the runtime issue of storing passwords. You can create an integration that sets the SSIS Environment to whatever is in your vault. Yes you can use windows auth with Oracle but I don't imagine you could practically implement this. It is never practical to store a password in SSIS by various protection methods. You need to use Environments for runtime passwords, and you need to enter them manually at design time.

Comment: I won't explicitly say how we get our passwords.  I will just say that at runtime the password is fetched in a secure manner, put in a variable, and the connection string, referencing the variable, completes the login to oracle or teradata.   we blank that password variable when we get the job ready for prod promotion.   So when we open it again, that's a password fail right there until we can get to the variable and put it in.  Can you think of some way around that?

Comment: When you say "Environments" is that some ssis feature or is that just environment variables?

Comment: https://www.sqlservercentral.com/steps/ssis-catalog-environments-step-20-of-the-stairway-to-integration-services

Comment: What happens in you use odbc connection with the embedded/saved password in the dsn?

Comment: We had moved to a new ssis with vs 2017 ent recently and I was testing all permutations and combinations of teradata and oracle connections to make sure they worked like I thought.  The answer here is that DelayValidation=True and ValidateExternalMetadata=false are not optional if you use teradata and oracle and don't provide a saved password.  And you have to set those things at 4 different levels.  That said if you define an Oracle task, don't provide a saved password, close the package, open the package, you just dinged yourself one failed oracle login.  That to me is bad design.

Comment: access_granted - our standard is not to use odbc but yes if you provide a saved password for oracle or teradata you won't have any problem.   Large scale production usually changes those passwords through the lifecycle (dev/uat/prod) so that wouldn't be a scalable solution for big companies.

Comment: I want to add to my comment above because of the space limitation.   "you just dinged yourself one failed oracle login ... and ssis doesn't tell you that you had a failed oracle login (it may be buried in an obscure log or it may show some connection manager as not connected).  Very experienced people with 10's of years of experience with oracle and teradata lock these id's in our group and they don't do that with any other tool.  To me if an Oracle login failed while using the client developer there should be an ssis popup that tells you that.